# Is this a typo (parameterised $n$-manifold)

Tags: differential-geometry, definition

In [this book here](https://books.google.com/books?id=rhq3YCguBOUC&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false) on page 62 parameterised $n$-manifolds are introduced.

The example given is that of a regular curve $\gamma (t) = (X(t),Y(t))$ and a parametrisation $\phi (x,y) := (x, y + Y(x))$. But I think there is a mistake in the book. Say $\phi$ is a local diffeomorphism at $(x_0,0)$ and $U$ is an open set containing $(x_0,0)$. They write:

...it is more convenient if $U$ can always be chosen so that the image $\phi (U)$ contains just one piece of $\gamma$. When this happens we say that the curve is a $1$-manifold.

> This should say $2$-manifold, right?

Of course, $\phi$ is the parametrisation and it is a map defined on $U \subset \mathbb R^2$. So we are talking about a $2$-dimensional manifold here.

**Edit**

(I will upload a screenshot of the relevant page)

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not a typo. The book is defining a "1-manifold" to be a plane curve such that every point in the curve has a neighborhood *in $\mathbb{R}^2$* diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^2$, with the curve taken to the $x$-axis. That is, locally, the curve looks like a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$. You're essentially throwing away the curves whose closures intersect themselves.

In broader context, the authors are defining a "1-manifold" to be a submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^2$. A subspace $N^n$ of a manifold $M^m$ is a submanifold provided the restrictions to $N$ of coordinate charts on $M$ are coordinate charts on $N$. This is equivalent to saying every point in $N$ may be enclosed by a coordinate neighborhood $U$ in $M$ whose coordinate chart takes $U$ to $\mathbb{R}^m$ and $N\cap U$ to $\{(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n,0,0,\ldots,0)\ |\ x_i\in\mathbb{R}\}$.

Comment: Thanks, now I was going to delete the question as I just figured it out myself but I would not consider that fair to you.

Comment: @MichaeldeSanta No worries, and thanks. In the future, when you figure out your own questions, consider answering them instead of deleting them. You are probably not the last person who's going to be confused about this. :)